# How to fade in and out a game object with two child game objects

Tags: unity

I have been fading game objects in and out using the following code. Now I want to fade out a game object with two child game objects. How can I do this?

```
    IEnumerator FadeToForGO(Material material, float targetOpacity, float duration, GameObject gameObj, bool isEnabled) {

    // Cache the current color of the material, and its initiql opacity.
    Color color = material.color;
    float startOpacity = color.a;

    // Track how many seconds we've been fading.
    float t = 0;
    if (isEnabled) {
        gameObj.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D> ().enabled = isEnabled;

    }

    while(t < duration) {
        // Step the fade forward one frame.
        t += Time.deltaTime;
        // Turn the time into an interpolation factor between 0 and 1.
        float blend = Mathf.Clamp01(t / duration);

        // Blend to the corresponding opacity between start & target.
        color.a = Mathf.Lerp(startOpacity, targetOpacity, blend);

        // Apply the resulting color to the material.
        material.color = color;

        // Wait one frame, and repeat.
        yield return null;

    }

    if (!isEnabled) {
        gameObj.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D> ().enabled = isEnabled;

    }

}
```

Comment: If you need tweening capabilities i suggest you check out [DoTween](http://dotween.demigiant.com/). You have to talk to each renderer individually if i'm not mistaken.